# Likelihood function for data y under given distribution with probability p

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am struggling with the following question: 
Consider a random variable (RV) Y that follows the distribution:
$$P(Y=y|p) = (1-p)^yp$$
where $y \in$ {0,1,2,..} is a non-negative integer, and p is the parameter of the distribution. Imagine we observe a sample of n non-negative integers y={$y_{1},....y_n$) and want to model them using the given distribution ( the data is independently and identically distributed).

> Write down the likelihood function for the data y ( i.e, the joint
> probability of the data under the given distribution with the
> probability parameter p )

I have got as far as the following ( I think) but am lost on the next step.

$\prod_{i=0}^y p \prod_{i=0}^y(1-p)^y$

I have tagged maximum-likelihood because there is no likelihood tag.

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood function of the parameter $p$ given the data $(y_1,\cdots,y_n)$ is
$$
L(p\mid y)=P(Y_1=y_1,\cdots, Y_n=y_n\mid p)=\prod_{i=1}^n P(Y_i=y_i\mid p)
$$
where $Y_i$'s are iid copies of $Y$.

Now you simply do the substitution.

Comment: How can I do that without knowing n?

Comment: @KirstenGreed that should be a given number.

Comment: @msramy apologies. I missed out the actual question text. I have updated now. We are not given what y is.

Comment: @KirstenGreed what is your actual question then?

Comment: I have now put it in quotes in the question starting "Write down the likelihood function ...

Comment: @KirstenGreed:  "likelihood function for data" does not make much sense... if you can show me the original problem, it would be not difficult to given an answer.

Comment: @KirstenGreed it is very likely that you copied the problem incorrectly. What book are you reading?